# Strange behavour of the UseSystemPasswordChar

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I made a small project to demonstrate my problem. I am trying to make a custom keyboard for an application and I make a reference to the original textbox in the new form, containing the keyboard.

My problem begins when I have the original textbox setup as a password textbox.

First of all, the demo project is just a windows forms window containing one button, the rest is in the code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TextBox tbxTemplate = new TextBox()
    {
        Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right,
        Multiline = false, 
        UseSystemPasswordChar = true
    };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Controls.Add(tbxTemplate);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form frmOnlineKeyboard = new Form();

        TextBox tbxShowKeys = new TextBox();

        frmOnlineKeyboard.Controls.Add(tbxShowKeys);

        //tbxShowKeys = textBox;

        frmOnlineKeyboard.Show();

        tbxShowKeys = tbxTemplate;
        tbxShowKeys.Multiline = false;
        tbxShowKeys.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    }
}
```

The first thing that happens is that the startwindow appear when I run the project. The small textbox is added and I can write in it and it displays the password char just fine.

When I press the button, a second window is created and the with a breakpoint I can verify that all the settings from `tbxTemplate` is transferred to the `tbxShowKeys`.

However, the text from the first textbox is not displayed, although it exists in the control in the breakpoint. I can live with that.

The problem I have is that the second textbox ignores the password flag and displays regular text and not the bullets.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't do this: `tbxShowKeys = tbxTemplate;` The settings are not *transferred*, you're assigning a reference, not copying properties. Remove that line.

Comment: E.g., if you set `tbxShowKeys.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;`, you'll see that you're changing `tbxTemplate`, not `tbxShowKeys` anymore.

Comment: Jimi, that is actually my goal. To assign a reference. So the keyboard function takes the calling textbox as an input parameter and all manupilations I do to the tbxShowKeys are reflected to the source textbox (in this case tbxTemplate). But it is not working´.

Comment: You cannot have the same *physical* Control in two different *places* at the same time and two different Parents. Use DataBindings instead. When you change the Text (as the bound property) in one of the bound Controls, the other is updated immediately. You can bind as many Controls as you like (well, all right... with a bit of conscience).

Comment: just read the text and assign it back to the first textbox, `tbxShowKeys = tbxTemplate` does not make any sense

Comment: Note that using DataBindings, the bound Controls are updated even if you show one of the bound TextBoxes in a Modal dialog (with `ShowDialog()`)